# Can't add a gate in order to prevent my code from entering the if second time

Tags: c++

That's the first if, which I don't want my code to enter second time, so I added a gate. I have another if, which has as a condition the counter to be equal to 3, so you can imagine that if I don't have a gate for the first if, my code will keep entering the first if, as 2 comes before 3 always. Now what's my problem... Whenever I add the condition with the gate and the line (gate=0) inside the if my code goes on an infinity loop. Also, if I set the gate in a different value than 1, I get the same infinity loop. Please help me.

EDIT: Below you can find a better example of my code in order to help me. Thank you :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {    
  ifstream file;
  file.open ("file.txt");
  ofstream file1;
  file1.open ("file1.txt");
  char counter = 0; 
  char ch;
  char x;
  string word;
  string word2;
  string word3; 
  int gate = 1;
  word.clear();

  while (file >> std::noskipws >> ch) {         
    if (ch == ' ') {
        ++counter;
    } 
    else if (ch != ' ') {
        counter = 0;
    }

    if ( (counter == 2) && (gate == 1) ) {
        gate = 0;
        x = file.get();

        while ( x != ' ' ) {
            word = word + x;
            x = file.get();
        }
        counter = 1;
        word2 = word;
        word.clear();
        file2 << word1 << " ";      
    }

    if (counter == 3) {
        x = file.get();

        while ( x != ' ' ) {
            word = word + x;
            x = file.get();
        }
        counter = 1;
        word3 = word; 
        word.clear();

        file2 << word3 << endl;
        word3.clear();
        gate = 1;
    }

    if (file.eof()) {
        break;
    }       
  }

  file.close();
  file1.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: We need a little more context to answer your question. You can remove some irrelevant stuff, but show us the surrounding code. Especially the code related to gate. My guess would be that you declare or initialize gate as a local variable inside the loop, so that each change you make here is forgotten the next time around.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @ThomasSablik  I did, thank you for the remark. Is it easier now for you to help me?

Comment: @Gerriet Thank you for the remark. Do you see any mistakes on my code?

Comment: Did you read the information in my link? Your code is not complete. It is not compilable. There is no main function.

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger to find your problem?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I posted the whole code. Is it better now?

Comment: Please provide the input and the desired output. Instead of files you can use [std::stringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream). Also you should format your code before posting. You can use http://format.krzaq.cc/

Comment: And please test and fix your code before posting. Your code is not compilable. `file2` is not declared.

Comment: @Gerriet EXACTLY!!!! I found it by myself yesterday evening but yeah, that was exactly my mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your endless loop is probably here:

```
  x = file.get();

  while ( x != ' ' ){
    word = word + x;
    x = file.get();
  }
```

If you reach the end of the input stream, x will become EOF, which is different from space and thus the while-loop will never be left. Do check for EOF or check the eofbit from the istream (file).